# Error with SQL Server procedure dynamic

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have written a SQL Server procedure which is working fine with most of the values but with some values it is giving me error as:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@CourseID".

I don't have much experience with procedures, please help, also see param definition and argument order.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[prStudentLoadByStudentAtt] 86
    @StID int
AS
   DECLARE @SemID int 
   DECLARE @CourseID int

   DECLARE @SQLQuery as nvarchar(4000)
   DECLARE @ParamDefinition as nvarchar(4000)

BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    set @SQLQuery = 'SELECT distinct dbo.tbSubjects.SubjectName,dbo.tbSubjects.SubCode, dbo.tbSubjects.SemID, dbo.tbStudent.StudentID, dbo.tbStudent.Name, dbo.tbStudent.RollNo, dbo.tbStudent.RegNo, dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.SubID, dbo.fnTotalDays(dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.SubID, dbo.tbStudent.StudentID) AS Total, 
                      dbo.fnNoOfDays(dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.SubID, dbo.tbStudent.StudentID) AS Present,  dbo.fnPerDays(dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.SubID, dbo.tbStudent.StudentID)  
                       AS Percentage, ISNULL(dbo.tbSemester.SemName, ''Not Available'') AS SemName
FROM dbo.tbAttendance INNER JOIN dbo.tbAttendanceMaster ON dbo.tbAttendance.MasterAID = dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.AtdID INNER JOIN dbo.tbStudent ON dbo.tbAttendance.StID = dbo.tbStudent.StudentID INNER JOIN dbo.tbSubjects ON dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.SubID = dbo.tbSubjects.SubID LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbSemester ON dbo.tbSubjects.SemID = dbo.tbSemester.SemID
   WHERE dbo.tbStudent.StudentID=@StID '

  SELECT  @CourseID = CourseID FROM tbStudent WHERE StudentID = @StID 
  SELECT  @SemID = SemID  FROM tbStudent WHERE StudentID = @StID   

  IF (ISNULL(@SemID, 0) = 0)
  BEGIN
      set @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery+'   and  dbo.tbStudent.CourseID=@CourseID '
  end
  else
  begin
      set @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery+'   and  dbo.tbStudent.SemID=@SemID '
  end

  set @ParamDefinition = '@SemID int, @StID int'

  Execute sp_Executesql @SQLQuery, @ParamDefinition, @SemID, @StID

  return 
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change these two lines to pass the `CourseId` into the dynamically created SQL

```
set @ParamDefinition='@SemID int, @StID int, @CourseId int'

Execute sp_executesql @SQLQuery, @ParamDefinition, @SemID, @StID, @CourseId
```

Comment: is the order of parameter important in these two lines or not

Comment: Yes, the order you define them in the first statement needs to be the same as the order you pass them in the second.

Comment: but in procedure StID is defined before semID but in paramdefinition  semid appears before stid and also in sp_excutesql

Comment: you can define them in any order in the procedure, but the `@paramDefinition` is a template that you have to follow when calling `sp_executesql`

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure why you have all this dynamic sql in here in the first place. Pretty sure your entire procedure can be reduced to a single select statement. Something like this.

```
select *
from dbo.tbAttendance a
INNER JOIN dbo.tbAttendanceMaster am ON a.MasterAID = am.AtdID 
INNER JOIN dbo.tbStudent s ON a.StID = s.StudentID 
INNER JOIN dbo.tbSubjects su ON am.SubID = su.SubID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbSemester sem ON su.SemID = sem.SemID
WHERE s.StudentID = @StID
    AND s.CourseID = isnull(su.CourseID, s.CourseID)
    AND s.SemID = ISNULL(su.SemID, s.SemID)
```

Comment: The queries the dynamic SQL generates may be more efficient.

Comment: That is a big assumption. The original approach required a minimum of three queries and is a very non-standard approach. Yes it is possible since the above is nonSARGable but I would certainly do some performance testing before going with dynamic sql approach as originally posted.